# bad reference to MS.Practices.Data

Tags: c#, dll

I have two project who reference to the same path of:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
```

I use

```
Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

one project compiles OK and the other shows error:

> Error 1   The type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Instrumentation.IInstrumentationEventProvider'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   <---in file
>   line.. -->    58  17  ControlPanel.Toolbar

Why might I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding the reference to `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll` to the project with the problem? Is it referenced in the other one with no problems?

Comment: No problem. It's easy to overlook something so simple like that sometimes.